# utilizar subscripciones en mercadopago checkout pro

Tags: php, mercadopago

¿Es posible **implementar las suscripcione**s con **mercado pag**o con **checkout pro** y SDK PHP (mercadopago/dx-php 1.8.1)?

Ya revisé los ejemplos del SDK, logre correr la subscripción básica pero no encuentro una manera de implementarlo con el checkout pro
ni la documentación alguien lo ha implementado?

La documentación sobre checkout pro esta aquí, pero no dice algo sobre las suscripciones:

[Documentación mercado pago checkoutpro](https://www.mercadopago.com.mx/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/introduction/)

Los ejemplos del SDK de PHP están aquí, pero no se han actualizado en 2 años por lo que tampoco he encontrado documentación de las clases o la interacción:

[SDK mercadopago/dx-php 1.8.1](https://github.com/mercadopago/dx-php/tree/master/samples/suscriptions)